# Strange problem with (inet6_aton()), returns null sometimes? SQL - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Can somebody explain what's going on here? Why does the row with name *sara* returns a null in IP_address? It´s the exact same code as the rest?

this line works perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ("","Nina", "Bertilsson", "nina-hej@bertilson.test.se", (inet6_aton('46.246.78.163')), now(), "nina", "password");
```

But this returns NULL for IP_Address with the inet6_aton function:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ("","Sara", "Andersson", "andersson@sara.se", (inet6_aton('46.246.65.892')), now(), "sara", "password");
```

The table is as follows:

[image]

I´m Using XAAMP with mariaDB.

Comment: Since `46.246.65.892` isn't a valid IP address, why would you expect a function that deals with IP addresses to do anything sensible with it?

Comment: ... and do not use doublequotes in MySQL for quoting string literals until single quotes usage is absolutely impossible by some exotic reason - if `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode will be enabled somewhen in future then your queries will fail.

Comment: well 46.246.78.163 is not valid either, so why does that work? 

@Akina aha ok thanks,

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses): "An IPv4 address has a size of 32 bits ... usually represented in dot-decimal notation, consisting of four decimal numbers, each ranging from 0 to 255". That's why were asserting that one of the addresses is invalid whilst the other appears valid.

Comment: *well 46.246.78.163 is not valid either* Why? each part value is in a range 0..255, the whole address is valid formally. Whereas in the second query the last byte value `892` is out of range.

Comment: aha THANKS!, was so focused to get the db-setup to work, but did not resarch the dummy-data and how ip-addressen works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your question that way:

Why the following query gives result:

```
SELECT HEX(inet6_aton('46.246.78.163'));
+----------------------------------+
| HEX(inet6_aton('46.246.78.163')) |
+----------------------------------+
| 2EF64EA3                         |
+----------------------------------+
```

while this one does not:

```
SELECT HEX(inet6_aton('46.246.65.892'));
+----------------------------------+
| HEX(inet6_aton('46.246.65.892')) |
+----------------------------------+
| NULL                             |
+----------------------------------+
```

It is because the first one is a valid IPv4 address:

```
SELECT is_ipv4('46.246.78.163');
+--------------------------+
| is_ipv4('46.246.78.163') |
+--------------------------+
|                        1 |
+--------------------------+
```

but the second one is not:

```
SELECT is_ipv4('46.246.65.892');
+--------------------------+
| is_ipv4('46.246.65.892') |
+--------------------------+
|                        0 |
+--------------------------+
```

The issue with the second one is with the number after the last dot - 892. It cannot exceed 255 but it does.

Comment: tanks a lot @philip petrov make it clear, my mistake to not be aware of how IP-addresses works.